# How do I disable the annoying auto-correction of punctuation on device keyboard?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, keyboard, text-editor, auto-correct

Here are two examples: (I'm using the '`|`' as the cursor)

Example #1:

```
I want to put the next word in quotes |
```

type '`"`' followed by a word and closing quote:

```
I want to put the next word in quotes" |
I want to put the next word in quotes" f|
I want to put the next word in quotes" fa|
I want to put the next word in quotes" fai|
I want to put the next word in quotes" fail|
I want to put the next word in quotes" fail"|
```

Desired (and expected):

```
I want to put the next word in quotes "|
```

Example #2:

```
I want a space before the question mark |
```

type '`?`' multiple times:

```
I want a space before the question mark? |
I want a space before the question mark? ?|
I want a space before the question mark? ??|
```

Desired (and expected):

```
I want a space before the question mark ?|
```

I have all the auto-correct options unchecked in my Motorola Flipside's settings:

[image: Motorola Flipside - device keyboard settings]

Comment: That's annoying.  Some of the soft keyboards do this too, I hate it.  I don't want anything I type to ever be changed, because I typo less often than the software screws it up.

Comment: @Matthew I know, it's so frustrating :-(

Comment: I believe the stock keyboard on 2.2 does not do that, type the word, space, quote, and another word, and a quote, and they all works just as you'd expect. I've tried reproducing the problem in Samsung keyboard, HTC's, and Swype, none of them seems to mess up with the spaces around ".

Comment: OK, I'll add the 2.1 tag, good to know.

Comment: I just tries to type in a user id an the b**dy keyboard caps the first character on «.». You have to backspace and type the «.» again several times to correct. Generaly the 2.3.3 keyboard is pretty good but with this I reactivate and suggest “Smart Keyboard PRO”. — I just hate Programs who think to be more clever then me. Of course they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [Vlingo](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vlingo-virtual-assistant/com.vlingo.client) and I switched over to that as the input method and I no longer have the above issues.